# Can't get list of files

Tags: ubuntu-one, file-sharing

when i click on folder, it says to me "OpenID transaction in progress" and button "Continue". Is it my network issue?

[image]

And when i press "Continue" button it goes on https://one.ubuntu.com/files/api/view/f/Mail for e.g.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is likely a bug on the server or a problem with your account. You should contact Ubuntu One support at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact instead.

Comment: Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
More information is available with DEBUG=True.

Comment: i can't even write to support, it's buggy everywhere, i've refreshed page but csrf hash goes wrong (

Comment: Then file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers perhaps. Or start with disabling all the extensions in your browser, because it's most likely one of them causing the problem.